# Express doesn't allow changing the CSP header

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, content-security-policy, websecurity

For some reason the latest Express.JS versions are forcing a default, restrictive CSP (Content-Security-Policy) header value.

I'm trying to instantiate a middleware in order to change CSP to a more permissive one (that's currently on my needs for the project) but Express.JS seems to ignore every value for the Content-Security-Policy header. Calling `res.setHeader("...", "some value")` does work on that middleware when I change the key name to everything but "Content-Security-Policy". I'm not defining this header anywhere else, so it seems to come from Express.JS itself. What's exactly going on, how to correctly make Express.JS to recognize it?

[image: example: requesting the main page shows the default restrictive header for CSP, ignoring the value I set on line 29]
*Example: requesting the main page shows the default restrictive header for CSP, ignoring the value I set on line 29*

[image: another example: changing the header to another name that's not CSP correctly enlists it to the headers]
*Another example: changing the header to another name that's not CSP correctly enlists it to the headers*

Comment: hey, i have the same exact problem.
did you solve it? How?

Comment: What's the version of `express`?