# CSP problem: How to configure CSP-headers with express/node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Yes, this is almost the same title of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191364/how-to-configure-csp-headers-with-express-node-js), also i see that the guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276114/express-doesnt-allow-changing-the-csp-header) has my exact same problem, but had no answers.

I'm trying to make my own version of [this utility](https://github.com/EarthstormSoftware/EliteFIPServer) and it works as long as i connect to the server using "localhost", but i get the `"Refused to load the script 'http://<my_IP_address>:3000/thescript.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "'script-src-elem 'none'"` error when i try to view the **http://*<my_IP_address>*:3000/widgets/route/** page from another PC.

I followed a lot of answers here, tried also using helmet, but in the end i didn't solve the problem, just like the guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276114/express-doesnt-allow-changing-the-csp-header).

Could someone suggest a working solution?